# swift cannot delete row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to delete a row in my ui `tableview`, so I created this method:

```
func showActionSheet(index: IndexPath) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Chat löschen oder melden?", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        if self.isFilter() {
            let object = self.filteredData[index.row]
            self.removeFromUser(openChatsId: object.openChatsId!)
            self.filteredData.remove(at: index.row)
        } else {
            let object = self.mDataset[index.row]
            self.removeFromUser(openChatsId: object.openChatsId!)
            self.mDataset.remove(at: index.row)
        }

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [index], with: .bottom)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Melden", style: .default, handler: { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.reportUser(index: index)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abbruch", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true)
}
```

But it raises this error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (11) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11)

Comment: Can you show your `numberOfRows(in section:)` method?